# converting whole project to CoffeeScript with js2coffee

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

**Problem**:

**js2coffe** does work only with **single file** input/output redirection.
to convert a whole project and it's directory structure can be a real pain.

Want to convert a **ExpressJS** default application project incl. it's directory structure?

Check out the script below

Comment: I hope you have a very complete test suite, js2coffee can do some odd things to your code. You're better off translating your code by hand or even better, leave it alone and translate it to CoffeeScript by hand piecemeal as you update the functionality.

Comment: that's more about using bash and stdin/out redirection to make life easier - besides there is cs2 lurking around: https://github.com/michaelficarra/CoffeeScriptRedux

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**UPDATE**: Please check the short version of this script below if you are in a hurry.

A simple Bash script does the Job for ya:

```
#!/bin/bash

for FILE in `find . -name "*.js" -type f -o -path './node_modules' -prune -o -path './components' -prune`
do 
    if [ -e $FILE ] ; then        
        COFFEE=${FILE//.js/.coffee}

        echo "converting ${FILE} to ${COFFEE}"
        js2coffee "$FILE" > "$COFFEE"
    else     
        echo "File: {$1} does not exist!"
    fi
done
```

make a file, for example all2coffee, put it in /usr/local/bin, add an `chmod + x` flag it in terminal

**REQUIREMENTS**

`js2coffee` installed globally, if not yet instaleld do: `npm install -g js2coffee`

**SCRIPT EXPLAINED**

**for loop:**

`` for FILE in `find arguments` .... `` means:

find output is assigned to `FILE` string every time `find` stumbles upon a .js file

**find parameters:**

`-name "*.js"`  grab all files with .js ending

`-type f` must be of type **file** since we don't want .js dir's but file's only

`-o -path './node_modules' -prune`

excludes files in dir's **`./node_modules`** adding **`-prune`** is crucial, otherwise find will descend into the dir and print **`*.js`** files found in the directory

**do block:**

`if [ -e ${FILE} ] ; then`

**-e** flag checks if the string from **`FILE`** is a existing file on the filesystem, otherwise `else` is executed.

**string manipulation:**

`COFFEE=${FILE//.js/.coffee}`

we assing thte `COFFEE` variable a string where we replace 
**.js** with **.coffee** through the bash string manipulation: `${STRING//match_this/replace_with}`

**conversion:**

`js2coffee "$FILE" > "$COFFEE"` we feed js2coffee with `FILE` and `COFFEE` as **strings**

**EXTRA:**

You like to move all of your converted .coffee files to a new directory, but keep the structure?

Use **find** with **`rsync`** in Linux or **`ditto`** on Os X since cp won't 
create directories needed by this command. Here a little script to execute in 
the main dir that will do the job

all .coffee files will in the /coffee dir copying the .js files hierarchy

```
for FILE in `find . -name "*.coffee"`
do 
    ditto .${FILE/./} coffee${FILE/./}    
done
```

*execute this **after** you converted your files to .coffee*

**UPDATE**

you can swap `ditto` or `rsync` with `mv` after the first run to move the files since `mv` like `cp` does not create sub dirs.

**UPDATE 2**

added an one liner for those on time, see my second answer below!

**UPDATE 3**

added an option to exclude `./node_modules` directory from conversion, for those who don't want to convert their dependencies

Answer (score 9):

**For those on short time - use this nifty one-liner!** 
It's start's in the current dir ./ and goes through subdirs 
grinding every `.js` file to `.coffee`

`find . -type f -name '*.js' | while read f; do echo "grinding $f to ${f/.js/.coffee} "; js2coffee "$f" > "${f/.js/.coffee}"; done`

want to **exclude** `./node_modules` directory from conversion? Use the one below instead:

`find . -path ./node_modules -prune -o -type f -name '*.js' | while read f; do echo "grinding $f to ${f/.js/.coffee} "; js2coffee "$f" > "${f/.js/.coffee}"; done`

*small tip:*
You can use this loop for moving or copying files as well: 
substitute the **js2coffee** command with whatever you need to do. 
`find` output (the list of found files) can be simply modified and filtered.

In bash, substring extraction (or replacement) is simple - as in the example above:

**IMPORTANT (long version)** 
bash variables are accessible by adding **$** in front of the variable's name - BUT initially they are defined **without** the **$** so for your mental health keep that in mind and check your code for the $var/var= syntax in case you got some not-so-logic errors showing up. I make this mistake over and over again after not doing anything in Bash for a while so I thought it would be wise share this simple truth (might also be me, being a lousy dev)

**IMPORTANT (short version)** variable definition: `var_name=value` variable access: `$var_name=value`, bad idea: `$var_name=value`, later on accessed by `$var_name`.

In the example, variable **f** is accessed by **$f**, accessed wth **${f}** we replace **.js** -> `/.js` (/ is a seperator) with **.coffee**  -> `/.coffee` like this: `${f/.js/.coffee}`.

```
apple="green"; 
echo $apple;
```

outputs:

`green`