# How to converting whole project to CoffeeScript with js2coffee on Windows 7

Tags: javascript, bash, coffeescript

I have a big project in javascript and i'd like to convert it to coffeescript. The problem is that **js2coffee works only  on a single file**.

This thread [converting whole project to CoffeeScript with js2coffee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14091818/converting-whole-project-to-coffeescript-with-js2coffee) didn't helped me **since I am on Windows**. I tried using git bash, but extra paths are not here : sh.exe tells me `node: command not found` when running `node -v`, and of course `js2coffee` gives `js2coffee: command not found`. Same for `npm`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Executing multiple commands from a Windows cmd script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197976/executing-multiple-commands-from-a-windows-cmd-script)

Comment: This isn't a coffeescript question, it's a cmd question, or a bash question. You just need to read the directory and execute js2coffee on all the js files.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally I found the solution: The script

```
for /r %i in (*.js) do (echo %i.js && js2coffee %i.js > %i.coffee)
```

worked but it appends the `.coffee` to the `.js` (`myfile.js.coffee`) so the working script

```
@echo off
for /r %i in (*.js) do (echo %~di%~pi%~ni.js && js2coffee %~di%~pi%~ni.js > %~di%~pi%~ni.coffee)
Pause
```